# Replacing complex string with special characters and spaces

Tags: shell, unix, replace, sed

I am using `find /path -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' {} \;` (Source: Stackoverflow). This is working fine. But, I want to replace string with spaces and special characters.

Old string -> `where acc_id = ".$_SESSION['acc_id']);`

New string -> `");`

I don't want to use regex. I have exact string. Is there any way to do it with above find and sed command or anything else?

Comment: Thanks. But i am new to this and confused. i have used it like `find /path -type f -exec sed -i 's/where acc_id = ".$_SESSION['acc_id']);/");/g' {} \;`. It is not working. Can you please tell a proper way to do this?

Comment: Does `[\'acc_id\']` work?